# How can I switch overlapped elements with CSS transitions?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here's the scenario: I have four elements overlapping one an other in a parent element, something like this:

```
<body class="one">
    <div id="overlapping">
        <div class="one">1</div>
        <div class="two">2</div>
        <div class="three">3</div>
        <div class="four">4</div>
    </div>
    ...
```

The CSS looks a little like this:

```
.one, .two, .three, .four { display: none; }
body.one .one,
body.two .two,
body.three .three,
body.four .four {
    display: block;
}
```

Then there's some javascript and some buttons to switch the class on 'body'.

This works great, except that I'd like to use a css transition to switch between the blocks. They are of uneven (and unknown) height, so I can't animate on height. I'd rather not hardcode any widths for [responsive](http://www.initializr.com/try) reasons, and transitions don't work on `display` yet.

I can't animate on `visibility` or `opacity` because the overlapped elements continue to take up space in the layout while hidden or transparent: i.e. they aren't truly overlapping unless the invisible ones have `display: none`.

(One working solution would be css to position all elements at the top left of `#overlapping`, obeying normal text-wrapping rules, on top of each other, such that `#overlapping` expands to hold them as if they weren't `position: absolute`. I've found no such method as of yet.)

So how do I animate the switch? Is there a way with CSS, or do I have to resort to js animations?

Comment: I know that the first one is `#overlapping > div`, but I wanted to be more explicit in the question. As for the second one, I don't think you're correct: the `.one` class is on the body, not `#overlapping`, because there are other elements in the body that also transition.

Comment: ...Because `.three` is only supposed to display when `body` also has `.three`. Similarly for `one`, `two`, and `four`. There's no way to compress them all into one binary `displayToggle` class. I don't know an easier way to do it than what I wrote above.

Comment: Because the elements take up space while transparent, and you end up with the overlapped elements all stacked up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I have found so far is as follows (less syntax):

```
body {
  #overflow > div
    height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
  }

  &.one .one,
  &.two .two,
  &.three .three,
  &.four .four {
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

#overflow {
  overflow: hidden;
  div {
    transition: height .9s;
    transition: opacity .9s;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
  }
}
```

It happens to work because all of my inner divs are the same (albeit variable) height. I'd still like a general solution, but nobody seems to know one.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are a few animations possible in css3 but I think its better to use JQuery

google jQuery API .animate

```
$(".one").animate({opacity: 0.4, display: "block"} , 1500);

$(".two").animate({opacity: 0.4, display: "none"} , 1500);
```

toy around abit with what your changing...

it might also help to set the div's postion to relative in order to overlap better

I hope it helps, if not tell me what else you need

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for a non-jquery solution. I was able to work around the problem with the solution below, and by tweaking the markup such that height:100% is desirable. This happens to work for me because all of my overlapping elements share a height, but it's still not a general solution.